# PgSQL default action on UPDATE | DELETE of foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, table-relationships

In PostgreSQL what is the **default action** over a child table referencing with foreign keys a parent table, on the `UPDATE / DELETE` events?

The possible ones listed are the following:

```
NO ACTION | RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT
```

I imagine it could be `NO ACTION`, but the official documentation does not specify it in the [events paragraph of the SELECT statement specs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html) (unfortunately, the deeplink to the paragraph is not referenceable).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's right there in the description of the `REFERENCES` clause

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html)

> `NO ACTION`
>
> .... This is the default action.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I put some effort for the second time, but I couldn't really find occurrences of `NO ACTION` or occurrences of `REFERENCES` in that page, which could clarify me that.